# CSS Darken image on hover - adding an href around it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this CodePen example to develop a clickable images with darken effect on hover:

```
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/373x300">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/373x100">
    <p>Wonder Women</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/373x300">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/373x100">
    <p>Batman</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/373x300">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/373x100">
    <p>Joker</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/373x300">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/373x100">
    <p>Bane</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pic {
  width: 373px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pic:hover > .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
}

.info {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
    $(".pic").hover(
  function(){
        $(".info", this).css("display", "block");
    }, function(){
        $(".info", this).css("display", "none");
});
```

It is important that the image can be clickable and somehow I just can't make it work... Any ideas, insights would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which image is supposed to be clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image with an anchor tag and assign href with #.

```
<a href="#"><img src="url"/></a>
```

Comment: That's my first go, initially, but this does not make an image clickable, overlay effect just omits the href tag. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Not to image for whole Div link is required.

```
 <a href="#"> <div class="pic"><img src="http://placehold.it/373x300">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="info">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/373x100">
                <p>Wonder Women</p>
            </div>
        </div></a>
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to write HTML.
anchor tag is an inline element, and div is a block element.

Comment: yes but putting <a></a> to only <img> wont solve the issue right?

Comment: @OmerBTW Under HTML5 it's perfectly acceptable to wrap divs with anchor tags.

Comment: Yes, this one works perfectly! All had to be wrapped inside an anchor tag. I had also a bug inside my code, another anchor tag, I removed it now and works great. Thanks for your reply and help.